# Qual è la differenza tra "umiltà" e "bassa autostima"?

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning, word-choice, difference

Buongiorno,

Vorrei sapere che differenza c'è tra l'essere umile ed avere una bassa autostima di sé? Questi concetti mi sembrano legati ma non riesco a percepire la differenza. Forse avere una bassa autostima significa pensare poco di sé mentre  essere umile potrebbe significare farsi percepire come di basso valore anche se effettivamente non è così o la persona non pensa così di sé.

Grazie per i vostri chiarimenti in proposito

Comment: *la netta differenza fra il più cieco amore e la più stupida pazienza*

Answer (score 4):

Essere [**umile**](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/umile/), riferito al livello sociale di una persona può significare avere origini modeste, non nobili oppure riferito al suo modo di comportarsi significa

> 3. a. Che non si esalta del proprio valore e dei proprî meriti, e si mostra invece sempre consapevole dei proprî limiti: è umile; è un
>      grande scienziato, eppure è molto u.; come sost.: Gesù ha lodato gli
>      umili di cuore; che assume un atteggiamento di rispetto e di
>      sottomissione verso gli altri: è molto u. con i superiori; è una
>      persona u. con tutti; mi professo della S. V. umilissimo servitore,
>      formula di cortesia un tempo usata spec. nella chiusa delle lettere e
>      oggi solo con tono di scherzo. In usi letter., che ha un portamento
>      modesto e mite: ella si sedea Umile in tanta gloria (Petrarca). b.
>      estens. Proprio della persona umile nell’animo e nei modi; che
>      manifesta umiltà: contegno u., portamento u.; stare in atteggiamento
>      u. e dimesso; parlare con voce u.; Voi che portate la sembianza umìle,
>      Con gli occhi bassi, mostrando dolore ... (Dante); per gli u. suoi
>      prieghi un poco di compassione gli venne di lei (Boccaccio)

Avere una **bassa autostima** significa invece essere in uno stato psicologico per cui non ci  si ritiene all'altezza di un compito o più in generale non ci si ritiene adatti ad affrontare la vita.

Sempre da Treccani per [autostima](http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/autostima)

> Considerazione che un individuo ha di sé stesso. L'autovalutazione che
>   è alla base dell'a. può manifestarsi come sopravvalutazione o come
>   sottovalutazione a seconda della considerazione che ciascuno può avere
>   di sé, rispetto agli altri o alla situazione in cui si trova. Di norma
>   l'a. viene meno negli stati di depressione, mentre si rafforza negli
>   stati maniacali.

Una persona può avere una alta autostima di sé ma comportarsi comunque in maniera umile nel rapporto con gli altri.

Comment: Grazie per la risposta. Io trovo che l'umiltà, più che riflettere un certo status sociale spesso però riflette proprio un atteggiamento verso gli altri e verso se stessi. Se, come scritto nel dizionario, uno vede costantemente i propri limiti invece che i propri punti forti, questo lo porterà indubbiamente ad una bassa autostima, non è così? Anche se forse questo potrebbe portarlo a lavorare sui se suoi punti deboli, non lo so. Grazie.

Comment: Figurati! E benvenuto su Italian.SE!

Comment: @JimmyJoslington: “l'umiltà, più che riflettere un certo status sociale spesso però riflette proprio un atteggiamento”: infatti, se vedi, sono due significati diversi di “umile”, che hanno in comune il fatto che la parola deriva dal latino *humus*, “terra”, e quindi si riferiscono a una posizione, in senso figurato, bassa, vicino alla terra.

Comment: Quandi l'umiltà è l'atteggiamento di essere molto in basso, cioè, di essere niente rispetto a tutti gli altri, come dici tu, essere vicino alla terra piuttosto che al cielo, tenere il capo in basso anziché in alto. S una persona che fa questo nn on ha una bassa autostima allora sta fingendo. Perché in Italia si da tanto valore all'atteggiamento umile? Quali vantaggi pratici può portare un tale comportarsi o pensare? Grazie.

Comment: @JimmyJoslington Il fatto di essere (o comportarsi da) persone umili non indica avere una bassa autostima, anzi forse è il contrario. Un esempio può essere un prete, o un religioso o un volontario. Si comportano con umiltà quindi senza superbia e offrono il loro aiuto ad altri. Uno con una bassa autostima invece è qualcuno che non crede in se stesso e soffre di questo.
Il comportarsi in maniera umile è un atteggiamento considerato lodevole.

Comment: Grazie, quindi l'essere umile non significa non credere nelle proprie abilità ma semplicemente non cedere che queste siano superiori a quelle degli altri. D'altra parte, a me sembra che l'unico modo in cui una persona possa stimarsi è se almeno alcune delle sue capacità siano superiori a quelle degli altri. Se così non fosse, la persona non sarebbe buona a niente e si sentirebbe demoralizzata.

Comment: Se una persona sa offrire aiuto agli altri dovrebbe sentirsi valorosa, magari anche migliore degli altri nel saper dare aiuto, quindi meglio degli altri da questo punto di vista, quindi non umile. Dimmi dove sbaglio.

Comment: Poi esistono due tipi di limiti, quellì dove si può migliorare, è quelli dove non si può. Quindi, sul quale di questi due dovrebbe focalizzarsi la persona umile?

Comment: @JimmyJoslington Valoroso indica una persona coraggiosa o di comprovata capacità professionale. Essere umili è diverso. Fare le piccole gentilezze quotidiane, trattare con gentilezza anche i più poveri, fare la carità sono azioni che ti rendono umile ma non coraggioso. Ovviamente ci sono azioni umili che richiedono anche coraggio come il mollare tutto e fare il missionario per esempio o il medico senza frontiere. Umiltà è fare qualcosa di buono per qualcuno senza lo scopo di guadagnarci qualcosa che non sia la felicità altrui.

Comment: @JimmyJoslington, mi sembra che qui stiamo virando verso l'etica e la psicologia, che sono un po' fuori tema su questo sito.

Comment: @DavidePaselli, quando il dizionario Treccani parla di valore, non penso intenda valore con il significato di coraggio ma con il significato di essere utili. Inoltre il medesimo dizionario non parla di gentilezze verso gli altri. Forse queste sono interpretazioni tue. Se non è così mostra la definizione di un dizionario che spieghi quello che hai spiegato tu.

Answer (score 4):

Umile è il contrario di superbo, arrogante, altezzoso, significa modesto, semplice, che è pienamente cosciente delle proprie capacità ma non se ne fa un vanto, sa che molti altri sono validi come lui/lei e sa cooperare con gli altri senza volersi mettere al primo posto. È cosciente dei propri talenti ma li vive come un dono da utilizzare per il bene comune.

La bassa autostima invece si riferisce ad uno stato psichico o mentale di persona sull'orlo della depressione. Non c'è quindi nessuna connessione fra l'essere umile e avere una bassa autostima; ripeto: l'umile è pienamente cosciente delle proprie facoltà e decide di non auto-lodarsi per esse.

Comment: Benvenuto/a su Italian.SE!